# Boolean assignment not catching, need to understand more

Tags: java, arrays, boolean-logic

```
public class MyClass {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       int[] nums = {1, 2, 9, 3, 4};
       boolean results = false;
       int end = nums.length;
       if (end>4)end=4;
       for (int x=0;x<end;x++)
       {
            System.out.println(nums[x]);
            results = (nums[x] == 9);
       }
       System.out.println(results);
    }
 }
```

The following code checks to see if a 9 is present in the first 4 elements of an array, yet using the boolean operator in this fashion seems to always fail if there are not more than 1 "9" in the first 4 elements of the array.

Why is this? Logically it seems that this should work, and it really helps me to understand better when I understand why something doesn't work.

Comment: You're overwriting the value every time.

Comment: Yeah, that makes me look dumb. Thanks for the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite `results` every time. As written, this'll tell you whether the *last* item in the array equals 9 (which it doesn't), not whether *any* item in the array equals 9.

You should assign `true` to `result` if `num[x] == 9`; otherwise, don't assign anything.

@lucumt's answer shows an example of how to do that. One other example, just replace

```
results = (nums[x] == 9);
```

with

```
results |= (nums[x] == 9);
```

where the `|=` assignment is equivalent to `results = results || (num[x] == 9);` - in other words, if *any* value is true, the entire expression will be true. (Note that @lucumt's answer is slightly more efficient because it's O(n) whereas this is Theta(n) - i.e. this will always run *exactly* `n` times, where `n` is the length of the list, but @lucumt's can end the loop early if it finds any 9).

Comment: Note that `a |= b` is synonymous with `a = a | b`, not `a || b` which additionally has short-circuiting behavior.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you have itetate all the elements,the result will be the result of the last element,

So you need to stop `for` when you find the match result

```
  for (int x=0;x<end;x++)
   {
        System.out.println(nums[x]);
         if(nums[x] == 9){
          result = true;
          break;
         }
   }
```

Comment: Better to use `x < end && !result` - it avoids an unnecessary `break`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I think it's unnecessary due to if  result is true,the iteration will stop

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The `break;` enhances efficiency because the loop can end early if it finds any 9. Otherwise, you can just use `results |= (nums[x] == 9);` like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are over writing the value each time. This means you are testing if the *4th* value is equal to 9.

you can solve your problem like so:

```
   boolean results = false;
   for (int x = 0; x < end; x++) {
       System.out.println(nums[x]);
       if(nums[x] == 9) {
           results = true;
           break;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   boolean isPresent(int[] nums, int val)
   {
       for (int x : nums )
       {
            if (nums[x] == val)
              return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Otherwise you rewrite a value every time you're checking

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a class. The method nignPresentInFirst4Elements(int[] arr) returns true if the given array contains a 9 in one or more of it's first 4 elements:

```
public class Test {

   private static boolean nignPresentInFirst4Elements(int[] arr) {
      if(arr == null)
         return false;
      for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(arr.length, 4); i++) {
         if(arr[i] == 9)
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[][] arrs = new int[][] {
         {5, 8, 9, 3},
         {5, 8, 9, 3, 8, 26},
         {5, 8, 9, 9},
         {5, 8, 23, 0}
      };
      for(int i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(toString(arrs[i]) + " | " + nignPresentInFirst4Elements(arrs[i]));
      }
   }

   private static String toString(int[] arr) {
      if(arr == null)
         return "null";
      String s  = "[";
      if(arr.length > 0)
         s += arr[0];
      for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
         s += ", " + arr[i];
      }
      s += "]";
      return s;
   }

}
```